# Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, syntax

I'm getting this error related to my PHP error-handling function.

```
Undefined offset:  1
```

Here's the error handling code:

```
function customError($errno, $errstr)
{
    error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr",1,"ah@mysite.com","From: ah@mysite.com");
    die();
}
//set error handler

set_error_handler("customError");
```

Can anyone help point out what's causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm sorry I misunderstood your question.

Extend your customError() function to take also $errFile and $errLine, so you'll be able to see where the error actually happens.

Here is the documentation http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: thanx MartinodF...atleast you have helped me out......I have got the error line and got my problem as well.....my file is running fine now.....Thanks a tonn man........